# Figure out if a geometric series converges, and if it does find the sum?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation, infinity

I have been stuck, trying to find out how to solve the summation from n=1 to ∞ where $a_n = \frac{(-3)^{n-1} }{ 4^n}$. I think it converges, however I can't figure out exactly how to prove it does. Right now I have as the $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ causes it to be 0, which would make it convergent, but I am not sure if that is right (it being $0$). Also, I am having trouble finding the sum, since there does not seem to be a common ratio.

Comment: Please lookup [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for proper notation. Do you mean $a_n=(-3)^{n-1} / 4^n$?

Comment: Yes. I didn't know how to do th proper notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**: $\dfrac{(-3)^{n-1}}{4^n} = \dfrac{1}{4}\cdot \left(-\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{n-1}$

Comment: I did not notice that. I got it now, thanks for the help!